# Verilog Temporary Variable

Tags: verilog, hdl

I tried to make a CMP instruction in Verilog. To keep the result of the substraction, I declared a wire. This is what the code looks like (It is executed in an `always` statement).

```
wire [data_width:0] tmp_wire = reg_accumulator - reg_x;

f_zero <= tmp_wire & 'hFF == 0;
f_carry <= tmp_wire & 'h100;
```

Now Icarus Verilog complains about a syntax error and that `reg_accumulator - reg_x` is not an `l-value`:

```
cpu.v:149: syntax error
cpu.v:149: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
```

And why does it complain? What would be the right approach to declare a temporary variable in a function / task?

```
module comparator(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] op_a,
    input [7:0] op_b
);

reg f_zero;
reg f_carry;

function compare;
    input [data_width-1:0] a;
    input [data_width-1:0] b;
begin
    wire [7:0] tmp_wire = reg_accumulator - reg_x;

    f_zero <= tmp_wire & 'hFF == 0;
    f_carry <= tmp_wire & 'h100;
end
endfunction

always @(posedge clk) begin
    compare(op_a, op_b);
end

endmodule // comparator
```

Comment: Assignments in an `always` block should be to `reg`s (as you rightfully declared `f_zero` and `f_carry`). You put the wire declaration and assignment inside the `always` so the error is for trying to update a `wire` in an `always` block which is illegal...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ok, but how can I declare something like a temporary variable?

Comment: Just like any other wire... You have the answer below. By the way, `reg_accumulator` and `reg_x` are not defined...

Comment: How should I declare a wire in a function with it's parameters? This is not going to work: ```function compare;
    input [data_width-1:0] a;
    input [data_width-1:0] b;
    wire [data_width:0] tmp = a - b;
begin
    
end
endfunction```

Comment: You shouldn't ask this in the comments. Either [edit] your question to properly reflect your question or open a new one

Comment: I think this was also part of my original question, but I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should use systemverilog and include this in a class or you can create a parameterized module:

```
module compare_zero_n_carry
# (
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8
  )
(zero, carry, a, b);

  /* ports */
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] a;  //.."reg_accumulator"
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] b;  //.."reg_x"
  output zero;
  output carry;

  wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] tmp_wire = a - b;

  assign zero = (tmp_wire & {DATA_WIDTH{1'b1}}) == {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
  //..HERE IM NOT REALLY SURE WHAT IS THE LOGIC FOR THE CARRY,
  //..IT SHOULD BE ONE BIT
  assign carry = (tmp_wire & {1'b1,{(DATA_WIDTH-1){1'b0}}});     
endmodule // compare_zero_n_carry
```

And instantiate it in the main *comparator* module as:

```
  input                   clk;
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  op_a;
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  op_b;

  wire f_zero;
  wire f_carry;
  reg f_zero_reg;
  reg f_carry_reg;

  compare_zero_n_carry
    # (
        .DATA_WIDTH (DATA_WIDTH)
      )
    compare_zero_n_carry_inst (
        .a      (op_a),
        .b      (op_b),
        .zero   (f_zero),
        .carry  (f_carry)
      );

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    f_zero_reg <= f_zero;
    f_carry_reg <= f_carry;
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a `wire` inside the `always` block.

```
wire [7:0] tmp_wire = reg_accumulator - reg_x;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    f_zero <= tmp_wire & 'hFF == 0;
    f_carry <= tmp_wire & 'h100;
end
```